# Установка title в завимости от поддомена

Tags: php, битрикс

Хочу устанавливать title в зависимоти от поддомена для этого пишу функцию, но почему-то не работает. Подскажите почему?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/test/"){   
   $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   $listDomain = array(
        "k.example.com"=>"В k",
        "s.example.com"=>"В s",
        "v.example.com"=>"В v",
        "t.example.com"=>"В t",
        "b.example.com"=>"В b"
    );
    function seoDomen($url){
        foreach($listDomain as $k=>$v){
            if($url == $k){
               $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", $v);
               $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", $v);
               $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("keywords", $v);
               return false;
            }
        }
    }
 seoDomen($url);
}
```

Comment: Можно же разделить домен и извлечь субдомен `$n = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

Comment: конечно можно, однако, задачу это не решает

Comment: Если есть субдомен, проблема его установить в title?

Comment: Мне не нужно именно субдомен в тайтл писать, если можите, то ответьте, почему именно моя функция не работает

Comment: С битриксом не знаком, однако есть ответ у соседей stackoverflow.com как изменить title даже после отправки заголовков

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `seoDomen` ничего не знает о переменной `$listDomain` - не та область видимости. Надо перенести инициализацию переменной внутрь функции.

Если включить вывод ошибок - сразу должны увидеть. Также нормальные IDE подсветят такую ошибку.

И то же самое с `$APPLICATION`. Функция о нём не знает. Нужно передавать как аргумент в функцию. Или вообще убрать использование функции:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/test/"){
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $listDomain = array(
        "k.example.com"=>"В k",
        "s.example.com"=>"В s",
        "v.example.com"=>"В v",
        "t.example.com"=>"В t",
        "b.example.com"=>"В b"
    );
    foreach ($listDomain as $domain => $title) {
        if ($url == $domain) {
            $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", $title);
            $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", $title);
            $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("keywords", $title);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Вариант с функцией. `$_SERVER` - суперглобальный массив, нет необходимости его передавать в функцию. А вот `$APPLICATION` нужно передать или же объявить глобальным `global $APPLICATION` внутри функции, чтобы функция стала его видеть (это работает, учитывая то, что в bitrix $APPLICATION уже задан как global).

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/test/") {
    function seoDomain() {
        global $APPLICATION;
        $currentHost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $listDomain = array(
            "k.example.com"=>"В k",
            "s.example.com"=>"В s",
            "v.example.com"=>"В v",
            "t.example.com"=>"В t",
            "b.example.com"=>"В b"
        );

        foreach ($listDomain as $domain => $title) {
            if ($currentHost == $domain) {
                $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", $title);
                $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", $title);
                $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("keywords", $title);
            }
        }
    }
    seoDomain();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой вариант решения, но всё таки интересно, как для функции всё таки выглядеть будет?

Comment: @ChromeChrome добавил вариант с функцией..